# Biblatex formatting, seek formatting Bibliography, but not in body

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I am seeking to format certain components of my bibliography (say author names in a different color), however, the formatting is also applying to citations used in the body of the document.

[image: Example]

In the above example, I want the name in the references to be formatted (small caps, in red), however, I **DONT** want it to apply in the actual citation.

Below is the MWE code for the above example. I would be highly appreciative if someone knows how to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\usepackage[natbib,backend=biber,firstinits=true,citestyle=numeric-comp,backref=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{dummy.bib}
    @ARTICLE{einstein1905electrodynamics,
      author = {Einstein, Albert},
      title = {On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies},
      journal = {Annalen der Physik},
      year = {1905},
      volume = {17},
      pages = {50},
      number = {891},
      abstract = {N/A},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{dummy.bib}

%THE FORMATTING IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}

%COMMENCE
\begin{document}
    Test citation by \citet{einstein1905electrodynamics}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some portion of code to *only* apply to the bibliography, not the citations, you can simply wrap it in

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  ...
}
```

So it will be executed right before the bibliography is built.

Your MWE then yields

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\usepackage[natbib,backend=biber,firstinits=true,citestyle=numeric-comp,backref=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{dummy.bib}
    @ARTICLE{einstein1905electrodynamics,
      author = {Einstein, Albert},
      title = {On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies},
      journal = {Annalen der Physik},
      year = {1905},
      volume = {17},
      pages = {50},
      number = {891},
      abstract = {N/A},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{dummy.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  %THE FORMATTING IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
  \renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{#1}}}
}
%COMMENCE
\begin{document}
  Test citation by \citet{einstein1905electrodynamics}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does that lave local scope, what if the document has multiple bibliographies, say at the end of each chapter?

Comment: @ADP For a more localised version, there is `\AtNextBibliography`, if that's what you are asking for. `\AtBeginBibliography` will affect all bibliographies, but bibliographies only, so its scope is limited to those; it will not affect following citations.

Comment: Cheers perfect.