# Small capital author name in reference list

Tags: natbib

I'm in trouble in finding the bibliography style matching my sense. I'm using the `natbib` package which style `plainnat` allows me to have nice name-year citations via `\citet` such as

*Gabriel et al (1974)*

However in the reference list at the end of my `article` I'd like to have the **author names in small capital letters** `\textsc` rather than small letters I currently get. To print the reference list I use at the end of the document

```
\bibliography{foo.bib}
```

and compile with `bibtex`.

This is my .bib entry

```
@article{lamb,
 author = {Gabriel, P. and Banks, T. and Rutherford, M.},
 title = {The lamb lies down on Broadway},
 year = {1974},
}
```

I've of course tried to write

```
author = {\textsc{Gabriel}, P. and \textsc{Banks}, T. and \textsc{Rutherford}, M.},
```

but I get the small capitals in the citation as well which I don't like.

I hope these info are enough. Thank you for any working solution.

Comment: A complete, compilable example i.e. code we can copy-paste-compile would be more useful than fragments. If Biblatex/Biber is an option, it is worth saying so as that is much easier to customise. (Although it may be dangerous for Bob, but that's off-topic here.)

Comment: this might help: [Biblatex formatting, seek formatting Bibliography, but not in body](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139828/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  `biblatex`, just add this in your preamble:

```
\let\mkbibnamefamily\textsc
```

or

```
\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

You can modify similarly `\mkbibnamegiven, \mkbibnameprefix` and `\mkbibnamesuffix`.

Comment: Hi, is there a solution with natbib though?